# When is padding required for encryption?

Tags: java, php, android, encryption, utf-8

I asked a question here [why AES java decryption return extra characters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35215385/why-aes-java-decryption-return-extra-characters) about getting extra characters when I decrypt the encrypted data. Thanks to a comment by user "Ebbe M. Pedersen" I now understand that the problem is not using the same padding mechanism in both the PHP and Android Java code. So I changed the Java code to

#### Java code

```
 public class encryption {

    private String iv = "fedcba9876543210";//Dummy iv (CHANGE IT!)
    private IvParameterSpec ivspec;
    private SecretKeySpec keyspec;
    private Cipher cipher;

    private String SecretKey = "0123456789abcdef";//Dummy secretKey (CHANGE IT!)

    public encryption()
    {
        ivspec = new IvParameterSpec(iv.getBytes());

        keyspec = new SecretKeySpec(SecretKey.getBytes(), "AES");

        try
        {
            cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5PADDING");//"AES/CBC/NoPadding"
        }
        catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e)
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch (NoSuchPaddingException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public byte[] encrypt(String text) throws Exception
    {
        if(text == null || text.length() == 0)
            throw new Exception("Empty string");

        byte[] encrypted = null;

        try {
            cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, keyspec, ivspec);

            encrypted = cipher.doFinal(padString(text).getBytes());
        } catch (Exception e)
        {
            throw new Exception("[encrypt] " + e.getMessage());
        }

        return encrypted;
    }

    public byte[] decrypt(String code) throws Exception
    {
        if(code == null || code.length() == 0)
            throw new Exception("Empty string");

        byte[] decrypted = null;

        try {
            cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, keyspec, ivspec);

            decrypted = cipher.doFinal(hexToBytes(code));
        } catch (Exception e)
        {
            throw new Exception("[decrypt] " + e.getMessage());
        }
        return decrypted;
    }



    public static String bytesToHex(byte[] data)
    {
        if (data==null)
        {
            return null;
        }

        int len = data.length;
        String str = "";
        for (int i=0; i<len; i++) {
            if ((data[i]&0xFF)<16)
                str = str + "0" + java.lang.Integer.toHexString(data[i]&0xFF);
            else
                str = str + java.lang.Integer.toHexString(data[i]&0xFF);
        }
        return str;
    }


    public static byte[] hexToBytes(String str) {
        if (str==null) {
            return null;
        } else if (str.length() < 2) {
            return null;
        } else {
            int len = str.length() / 2;
            byte[] buffer = new byte[len];
            for (int i=0; i<len; i++) {
                buffer[i] = (byte) Integer.parseInt(str.substring(i*2,i*2+2),16);
            }
            return buffer;
        }
    }



    private static String padString(String source)
    {
        char paddingChar = ' ';
        int size = 16;
        int x = source.length() % size;
        int padLength = size - x;

        for (int i = 0; i < padLength; i++)
        {
            source += paddingChar;
        }

        return source;
    }
}
```

Then I added the same `PKCS5padding` functions to my PHP `mcrypt` class:

#### PHP mcrypt class

```
class MCrypt
{
    private $iv = 'fedcba9876543210'; #Same as in JAVA
    private $key = '0123456789abcdef'; #Same as in JAVA


function MCrypt()
{
}

function encrypt($str) {

    //$key = $this->hex2bin($key);
    $iv = $this->iv;

    $td = mcrypt_module_open('rijndael-128', '', 'cbc', $iv);

    mcrypt_generic_init($td, $this->key, $iv);
    $encrypted = mcrypt_generic($td, $str);

    mcrypt_generic_deinit($td);
    mcrypt_module_close($td);

    return bin2hex($encrypted);
}

function decrypt($code) {
    //$key = $this->hex2bin($key);
    $code = $this->hex2bin($code);
    $iv = $this->iv;

    $td = mcrypt_module_open('rijndael-128', '', 'cbc', $iv);

    mcrypt_generic_init($td, $this->key, $iv);
    $decrypted = mdecrypt_generic($td, $code);

    mcrypt_generic_deinit($td);
    mcrypt_module_close($td);

    return utf8_encode(trim($decrypted));
}

protected function hex2bin($hexdata) {
    $bindata = '';

    for ($i = 0; $i < strlen($hexdata); $i += 2) {
        $bindata .= chr(hexdec(substr($hexdata, $i, 2)));
    }

    return $bindata;
}

function pkcs5_pad ($text, $blocksize)
{
    $pad = $blocksize - (strlen($text) % $blocksize);
    return $text . str_repeat(chr($pad), $pad);
}

function pkcs5_unpad($text)
{
    $pad = ord($text{strlen($text)-1});
    if ($pad > strlen($text)) return false;
    if (strspn($text, chr($pad), strlen($text) - $pad) != $pad) return false;
    return substr($text, 0, -1 * $pad);
}}
```

**Now** the current problem is sending/receiving `UTF-8` characters, not  how to decode/encode `UTF-8` characters. 
When i send Arabic/Persian words which contain for example more than 3 or less than 3 characters it returns nothing.
For example:
If I send the word "خوب" (which has exactly 3 characters) I get "خوب"  which is correct; but 
if I send مچکرم (which has 5 characters) I get nothing.

I found that the problem is that I was not using the unpadding function after decrypting the data in my php code, so I fixed that:

#### PHP code

```
<?php
$data =file_get_contents('php://input');
$block_size=mcrypt_get_block_size("rijndael-128",'cbc');
require_once "encryption.php";
$etool=new MCrypt();
$data =$etool->decrypt($data);
$data=$etool->pkcs5_unpad($data);//  <------ using unpad function
$data =json_decode($data, true);



$data=$data["request"];
$etool=new MCrypt();
$data=$etool->pkcs5_pad($data,$block_size);
$data=$etool->encrypt($data);
$array=array('data'=>$data);
echo  json_encode($array);
```

#### And here is the Java code to get it

```
JSONObject j=new JSONObject(sb.toString());//sb is string builder
result=j.get("data").toString();
result= new String(etool.decrypt( result ),"UTF-8");
result = new String(result.getBytes("ISO-8859-1"));
Log.d("success remote ",result);
```

Now the problem is reversed!! I can get words containing more than or less than 3 Persian/Arabic characters, but not words containing *exactly* 3 characters.

I think I should check "does unpadding required?" but how if so?

Comment: > `return utf8_encode(trim($decrypted));` Why are you passing this to `utf8_encode()`? That function is probably not what you want.

Comment: thank you for writing. the messages java send to php some times  contain English characters.some time are just Asian and some time English/Asian .

Comment: i do not have any problem to send and receive English characters and i dont need these tow lines of code in java "UTF-8" and "ISO-8859-1". but when sending Asian character specially Farsi characters i need(i dont know why) both and if i dont use them the result is getting  weird words. finally i found what was the problem. as i said in the question i think padding should be done in special condition. i will answer my question.

Answer (score 1):

```
function pkcs5_pad ($text, $blocksize)
{
    $pad = $blocksize - (strlen($text) % $blocksize);
    return $text . str_repeat(chr($pad), $pad);
}

function pkcs5_unpad($text)
{
    $pad = ord($text{strlen($text)-1});
    if ($pad > strlen($text)) return false;
    if (strspn($text, chr($pad), strlen($text) - $pad) != $pad) return false;
    return substr($text, 0, -1 * $pad);
}
```

This code is using PHP's string functions, which operate on raw binary by default and ignores encoding.

Blending your decrypted messages through `utf8_encode()` doesn't actually make sense. That function remaps ISO-8559-1 codepoints (i.e. `0x00` through `0xFF`) to UTF-8 codepoints (i.e. `0x00` through `0x7f`, then `0xc280` through `0xc2bf` and `0xc380` through `0xc3bf`).

Since PHP operates on raw binary by default, you don't need to apply this transformation at all.

Note: I said *by default*. There's a very stupid feature in PHP called [function overloading](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/mbstring.overload.php) which is controlled by the `mbstring.func_overload` PHP.ini directive. If you're *using* this feature, you need to rewrite **every** piece of cryptography code that needs to measure and/or slice strings to **not** use `strlen()`, `substr()`, etc.

Defuse Security published and maintains a [secure authenticated encryption PHP library](https://github.com/defuse/php-encryption), which contains replacements for these functions that [resist function overloading](https://github.com/defuse/php-encryption/blob/399fc4c4798b301681888c2608b0ddd060d477da/src/Crypto.php#L622-L690).

---

**Security Notice**

First: [Your crypto code is broken](https://tonyarcieri.com/all-the-crypto-code-youve-ever-written-is-probably-broken). In other words: **NOT SECURE**.

Second: [Avoid ever using mcrypt for anything if you can help it](https://paragonie.com/blog/2015/05/if-you-re-typing-word-mcrypt-into-your-code-you-re-doing-it-wrong).

[If you just need your data to be encrypted over the wire, just use TLS](https://gist.github.com/tqbf/be58d2d39690c3b366ad). Trying to reinvent the wheel here will just lead to disaster.

However, if (for example) you need peer-to-peer encryption on top of TLS (e.g. so your server never sees the data),  don't roll your own. [Pick a secure PHP cryptography library](https://paragonie.com/blog/2015/11/choosing-right-cryptography-library-for-your-php-project-guide) instead. If you need one that works cross-platform, [use libsodium](https://paragonie.com/blog/2015/09/how-to-safely-implement-cryptography-in-any-application).

Comment: thank you for your attention about security notices. i learned a lot from second security notice link. specially :                                                **Surprise! MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256 doesn't mean AES-256.
All variants of AES use a 128-bit block size with varying key lengths (128, 192, or 256). This means that MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128 is the only correct choice if you want AES**

Answer (score 0):

the problem is about not properly using un-padding function in php code. actually when encrypting data in java, some times because the text **does not fit the block** it use padding for it and if the text fits, it does not do so. in PHP code, if padding was used in java encryption process, un-padding is done correctly. but if text does not need padding in java encryption process, PHP un-padding function returns null and null was passed to $data variable. so i get nothing!!!
by changing few lines of php code every think start working correctly.

**The code that cause the problem:**

```
$data=$etool->pkcs5_unpad($data);// in some cases null is retuned
$data =Json_decode($data,true);
```

**the correct version of the code: issue is fixed.**

```
$padding=$etool->pkcs5_unpad($data);
if($padding!="")
{
  $data=$padding;
}
$data =json_decode($data, true);
```